# How to handle XML deserialization with a changing schema

Tags: c#, xml

We have a service that's receiving data in XML, and there's an accompanying namespace/schema definition that usually changes once a year, sometimes more.

The schema describes a very large object and we only use a small portion of it that has not changed in at least 2 years since I've been handling it. However, the schema change forces us to re-generate the C# classes, re-build and re-deploy the application.

It would be good to not have to touch the application unless there's a change in the parts that we use.

For a separate throwaway application that was set up with a certain namespace, I had the code replace the incompatible namespace with the compatible one and deserialize the data that way.

Is there a solution for this problem that's more elegant?

Edit: the data we receive is only the subset of the whole schema, that's why it's not a problem to deserialize it with the namespace replacement.

Comment: It is not the schema that is the issue but really the namespaces.  There are ways to parse an xml and allow for changing namespaces provided the actual data structure is the same.  Normally the namespace is in the root element and using Xml Linq you can get the root element and then get the default namespace.

Comment: As I'm trying to get around the issue, it seems the deserializer is more interested in the namespace attributes on the classes than what's in the XML itself. Each class the xsd tool generates gets a `[RootAttribute(Namespace = 'http://namespecehere')` attribute. If I comment that out, the deserialization works.

Comment: I think commenting out the RootAttribute is a good solution.  The xsd tool is generating the classes automatically from the schema.  You have two situations 1) The updates to the xml do not require the classes to change for your application, but the namespace changes.  So you do not need to update the c#. 2) The updates require the classes to change for your application. So you are going to recompile and crate new classes from xsd tool.  Then you need to comment out the RootAttribute again as part of you build process.